# fs.existsSync is not a function in node error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am getting this when running node in Ubuntu 14.04,  'fs.existsSync'  is not a function . the code is

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 fs.existsSync(buildDescFile);
```

The version of node is v0.10.25 . Am I missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have forget to require the module `fs` :

```
var fs = require("fs")
```

Anyway, you'd better use [`openSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_opensync_path_flags_mode) and handle the error if the file doesn't exists :

> `fs.exists()` is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons.
>   There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code.
>
> In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an
>   anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another
>   process may remove the file between the calls to `fs.exists()` and
>   `fs.open()`. Just open the file and handle the error when it's not
>   there.

Comment: Actaully I added the require  for fs

Comment: `fs.existsSync()` will *not* be deprecated. The refered link states clearly that "[...] `fs.exists()` is deprecated, but `fs.existsSync()` is not. (The callback parameter to `fs.exists()` accepts parameters that are inconsistent with other Node.js callbacks. `fs.existsSync()` does not use a callback.)"