# How to use fs.WriteFile() in Angular 2 for updating .json file.?

Tags: angular

I tried importing file-system (`import * as fs from 'file-system'`) to use `fs.WriteFile()` in an Angular 2 application.

But I am getting an error :

> fs.existsSync is not a function

Can anyone help in using `fs.writeFile()` in Angular ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339580/fs-existssync-is-not-a-function-in-node-error is this any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the  file system from the browser. In order to write a file you have to do it on the server side, for example using node. There you can use the file-system module.